# How can I install Postgres GUI in Fedora 10?

Tags: postgresql

On my server I have Postgres 8.4, but there is no GUI included, so I need to install one. Is that possible? How is it done?

Comment: probably better asked on SF

Answer (score 1):

Download [pgAdmin3](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/), install and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

yum install pgadmin3